# How Do I Replace [] With array() in php

Tags: php

I have a variable

```
$x = '[["somecode",0,0,0],0,0,[[["somecode",0,0,0,0],0],0],]';
```

and I want to replace [ with array(  and ] with )

$x displays fine with echo $x;
but then I get an error when I try to :

```
$y = str_replace(array("[","]"), array("array()",")"), $x);

echo $y;
```

> Notice: Undefined variable: y in dir to .php file on line 64

and I'm trying to get:
`$pd` is sample data from a database before it goes through the `str_replace();` it displays fine.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: The braces are unbalanced in that string... Apart from that this looks like a json string. Sure you cannot simply use `json_decode()` for this?

Comment: There is also a trailing `,` (comma), but that does not explain why str_replace fails

Comment: The str_replace works fine. It generates junk but it does not fail and it is possible to `echo $y` so you problem is not in this piece of code. Please **Show the exact and complete** error message, and amke sure you have found the correct file and line where the error message says

Comment: Yes same I have seem to have fixed it ????? some how. But I don't know what I did :-(

Comment: Im curious, what are you trying to achieve by this exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this with your code and it replace as you want. Look at the below code.

```
<?php    
    $x = '[["somecode",0,0,0],0,0,[[["somecode",0,0,0,0],0],0],]';
    $y = str_replace(']', ')', str_replace('[','array(', $x));
    echo $y;
?>
```

Comment: OK I got this working I had a typo (found it after posting this sorry)

Comment: also how can i now use this so i can assess y as an array and not a string thanks.

Comment: p.s I want to avoid using eval()